# sed (regex) not working properly

Tags: regex, sed

I have to separate out an expression from the following piece of HTML code:

```
<div class="summary">
                <h3><a href="/questions/30727515/why-is-executing-java-code-in-comments-allowed" class="question-hyperlink" title="The following code produces the output &quot;Hello World!&quot;. (No really, try it) public static void main(String... args) { // The comment below is no typo. // \u000d System.out.println(&quot;Hello ...">Why is executing Java code in comments allowed?</a></h3>
    <div class="tags t-java t-unicode">
        <a href="/questions/tagged/java" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;java&#39;" rel="tag">java</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/unicode" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;unicode&#39;" rel="tag">unicode</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="started">
        <a href="/questions/30727515/why-is-executing-java-code-in-comments-allowed/?lastactivity" class="started-link">modified <span title="2015-06-15 17:43:58Z" class="relativetime">yesterday</span></a>
        <a href="/users/388520/zwol">zwol</a> <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 52560" dir="ltr">52.6k</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part which I want starts from .... 'title="the following code produces the outp ..........executing Java code in comments allowed?' all the way upto the end of 'a' and 'h3' tags.

Due to various reasons, I have to only use either sed or awk.

I have tried various regular expressions. Since the **required part may sometimes even span multiple lines** , I have used the following sed command: (Since .* matches only upto a newline character)

```
    sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*<h3><a href="\/questions\/.*link" title="\(.*\)<\/a><\/h3>.*/\1/p;}' Trial.html
```

I am getting no results with this. However, If I remove the end part:

```
    sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*<h3><a href="\/questions\/.*link" title="\(.*\)/\1/p;}' Trial.html
```

I am able to catch the beginning of my required string and it prints upto the end.

I have also referred to this serverfault.com question, for help:
https://serverfault.com/questions/315145/regex-for-sed-to-grab-multiple-lines-or-a-better-way

**Edit:**

There could be other similar  blocks also. I don't have to stop at the first result. I have taken the html from this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

This is another question which is very similar to mine!
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/text-between-two-tags

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indent the code. If you want to parse input that spans multiple lines, please include a sample of such input.

Comment: Doing this with sed or awk is a terrible idea. Don't you have *something* that can parse HTML properly? Perl or Python would do.

Comment: @Tichodroma -- I have put the sed command in the code blocks. Please suggest any other edits if required.

Comment: @Wintermute -- Yeah, actually I have implemented this in Python already. But I need it to do it sed/awk also

Comment: Use a DOM parser. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*<h3><a href="\/questions\/.*link" title="\(\.*\)<\/a><\/h3>.*/\1/p;}' Trial.html
```

That line puts everything in hold space, than after file is read, swaps it to pattern space to be used for multi line parsing.

modification idea, instead of grouping \(\.*\) which by the way is not correct since you've escaped here '.' so it's not any character but literal '.'
you could use title="\([^<]*\) which will catch all characters till first '<'.

Also if title=" is only once present in file than no need for many letters in first part of pattern, only ^.*title=" will be enough.

Comment: I did the corrections you suggested. I had put the \ after '.' by mistake. My problem still is not resolved, as there could be many more such titles in the file ...... My problem is similar to this question:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/text-between-two-tags

Comment: This method only returns the first match.....I want other such matches to be printed too.....The html is from the page: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

Comment: if <h3> tags are on one line, then why not parsing them first, to clear giberish, like sed -n '/<h3>/p' and will not look upon this question more if reasons for sed|awk must are not stated and acceptable.

Comment: I don't want to go writing python scripts for scraping this data when bash sripts are able to do the same. Also, I want to know the quick dirty way of doing this as a small temporary solution. I can and have used Beautiful Soup for better solutions.

Comment: more interersting question is  why people preffer scrapy over beautiful soup which by my opinion is better. For question related, if you like to sharpen sed/awk skills then getting some book(s) for them is better direction. Yes I understand what you mean by using command line one liner tools. But advice from experienced users is always avoid sed/awk in xml kind languages

Comment: Yes, actually I am in the process of buying a book. However to get some ideas I am trying out certain problems. I fail to gather why a similar question 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/text-between-two-tags 
gets 10 upvotes, it gets a downvote here. 
Also, if in a program i can run execute small bash scripts, why taking the pain of installing python/php, to just analyze some data.

Comment: before were -2, i've set +1, now is -1. For sed for start enough are famous sed one liners. All that knowledge is linux/bash related as main topic, which is good to know (not for money ; for heart). Also if you like dirty tricks perl is good  direction, but! no money in sed/awk/perl.

Comment: Okay, I will follow your suggestion to try this out via perl scripts.